# Why does Kaiki keep changing shirts?

Tags: monogatari-series

In episodes 21 and 22 (at least towards the beginning of the latter episode) of the "second season", we see Kaiki in a number of shirts in the same scene in the Okinawan cafe.

He first appears in a pink shirt (which he wasn't initially wearing in the airplane):

[image]

Before changing to a blue shirt and a yellow shirt:

[image] [image]

In the toilet, we see him in what appears to be a different pink Hawaiian shirt, and in the beginning of episode 22, we see him in an orange shirt:

[image][image]

The changes in shirt seem to coincide with "pauses" in the conversation - e.g. pauses indicated by the "black screen", or Kaiki's own thoughts (accompanied by images such as departing airplanes). But the conversation between Senjogahara and Kaiki probably takes place over a bit more than the course of one afternoon. If that's the case, should Kaiki's changes of shirt be taken as something stylistic without much meaning, or is there some significance to it?

Comment: I think one useful thing to keep in mind is that this part is narrated by Kaiki - we're seeing the world as Kaiki describes it. And, Kaiki being who he is, he's probably lying to us about what he sees, for whatever reason.

Comment: @senshin - yeah I figured that might have some relation to what was going on in that episode. A lot of what Kaiki says is most definitely straightout lying (e.g. he says he doesn't know Senjogahara earlier), and that makes sense on a visual level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, the interior coloring of the cafe changes too. We could assume that they're moving together to a new place every now and then, or that the cafe decorator is currently working 400% with customers still in the cafe. Senjougahara also changes her "disguises" between scenes. We can assume they have enough money to afford all that, and are changing between their meetings.

But what's really going on is probably just Shaft doing a comedy thing with changing decorations to somewhat lighten up the mood of a very serious discussion between Kaiki and Hitagi.

Comment: I somehow didn't quite catch Senjogahara's changes in disguise as well (though in retrospect they clearly did change).